# Configuration of CustomJacksonMapper to deal with DateTime is not working on Spring 4.1.5

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jodatime

Here are the configurations that I've made:

My config file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <!-- Support for Joda Time -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="customJacksonMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

My class that extends Object

```
@Component("customJacksonMapper")
public class CustomJacksonMapper extends ObjectMapper {
/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Instantiates a new custom jackson mapper.
 * 
 * RegisterModule = Registar o módulo do JodaTime.
 * Locale = Padrão portugues Brasil.
 * TimeZone = Converte para o timezone de São Paulo.
 * 
 */
public CustomJacksonMapper() {
    this.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    this.setLocale(new Locale("pt_BR"));
    this.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS , false);
    this.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
}
```

}

With this configuration, as I've read on a lot of posts, the date should be returned on the correct format in Json, but what I got is the following:

```
{"date": 1467920285301}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the version of my Spring project to 4.2.6 RELEASE. Doing that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to constructor:

```
this.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is the date still serialized in the same way? Also, could you provice code in which you are using this custom mapper?

Comment: Yes the date is comming serialized in the same way. This custom mapper is used by spring, I just overrided the ObjectMapper of Spring to use the CustomJacksonMapper